# Reference for solutions to singular integrals

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for a reference that provides a detailed solution for weakly singular integrals of type: $$(T_\gamma \phi)(x)=\int_0^1|x-y|^{-\gamma}\phi(y)dy=f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ is known and $\phi$ is the unknown function to be found. In particular, I would like to get references where numerical approximations for the index $\gamma$ is found for $0<\gamma<1$. I checked the references below but I was unable to find an example of the type above.

**References**

Muskhelishvili, N. I. (2008). *Singular Integral Equations: Boundary Problems of Function Theory and Their Application to Mathematical Physics* (Dover Books on Mathematics).

Erdogan, F. (1969). Approximate solutions of systems of singular integral equations. *SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics*, 17(6), 1041-1059.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following book which contains most of what I was looking for:

Delves, L. M., & Mohamed, J. L. (1988). *Computational methods for integral equations*. Cambridge University Press

Any similar reference(s) is welcome.